# Java 8 generics troubles with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have interface:

```
public interface AddableBox<T> extends Box<T> {
    public AddableBox<T> add(AddableBox<T> other);
}
```

And some class to use it:

```
    public class TestClass {
        public <T extends AddableBox<?>> void SomeMethod(T a1, T a2){
            a1.add(a2);
    }
}
```

a1 and a2 in example must be same types.

This code generates error:

> The method add(AddableBox) in the type AddableBox is not applicable for the arguments (T)

How to fix it? Sorry if duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the wildcard you're using in the bound `AddableBox` of declaring the type parameter `T`.  One `AddableBox<?>` cannot be the same type as another `AddableBox<?>`, and your `add` method in `AddableBox` mandates that they be the same.

You can use `T` itself as the type parameter for the bound.  Change

```
public <T extends AddableBox<?>> void SomeMethod(T a1, T a2){
```

to

```
public <T extends AddableBox<T>> void SomeMethod(T a1, T a2){
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. Previous version of method was: `public <TValue extends AddableBox<T>, T> void SomeMethod(TValue a1, TValue a2){
   a1.add(a2);
  }`. It is possible to use one generic argument?

Comment: But I not understand how it use. For example, i want to use AddableBox<Integer>. Integer does not extends AddableBox<Integer>...

Comment: If you have an `AddableBox` implementation, then the type parameter should be that class itself.  E.g. If you have `IntegerBox` extending `AddableBox<IntegerBox>`, then 2 `IntegerBox`es can be passed to the `SomeMethod` method.